# NMAP NSE call shell script

Tags: nmap

Is it possible to call external unix programs from nmap nse scripts just like with system(), exec() from php or C?

I already tried to use cmd, cmd.local.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Lua's [`os.execute`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.execute) function to do this.